# issue in custom PayloadFactory in wso2esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, payload, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2esb 4.7.0 and wso2dss 3.1.0..Actually as per my proxy configuration it's working fine..Even it displays success message at sever side but does not at client side and that is the issue..For this my last sequence configuration is like :

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Group_Seq3" onError="fault">
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
       <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
       <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" name="userid" expression="//s:userid/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
       <log level="custom">
          <property name="service called" value="Group_seq3"/>
          <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="userid" expression="get-property('userid')"/>
          <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="usergroupid" expression="get-property('usergroupid')"/>
       </log>
       <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
       <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
          <format>
             <p:Capp_insert_into_musergroupdetails_op xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                <p:usergroupid>$1</p:usergroupid>
                <p:userid>$2</p:userid>
             </p:Capp_insert_into_musergroupdetails_op>
          </format>
          <args>
             <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="get-property('usergroupid')" evaluator="xml"/>
             <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="get-property('userid')" evaluator="xml"/>
          </args>
       </payloadFactory>
       <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
       <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
       <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" action="remove" scope="axis2"/>
       <send receive="Group_Seq4">
          <endpoint>
             <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/Capp_GroupDataService/" format="soap11"/>
          </endpoint>
       </send>
    </sequence>
```

and Group_Seq4 is the sequence where i have written a custom payload configuration for proper responce like:

```
   <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Group_seq4" onError="fault">
   <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
   <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
   <log level="full"/>
   <payloadFactory>
      <format>
         <ResponseJSON xmlns="">
            <Body>
               <Datalist>
                  <Data>Successfully Rows inserted</Data>
               </Datalist>
            </Body>
            <Status>200</Status>
         </ResponseJSON>
      </format>
   </payloadFactory>
   <log level="custom">
      <property name="Capp_UserGroupDetail_Seq" value="just before send"/>
   </log>
   <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
   <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
   <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" action="remove" scope="axis2"/>
   <send/>
</sequence>
```

At server side it showing :

```
[2014-07-07 17:16:07,836]  INFO - LogMediator service called = CappGroupService, requester userid = 395885751788635281, username = intelligynt.com/tusar|395885751788635281, password = 123456, contactname = sps14youtility14, phonenumber = 47390686756, userdetails = <usergroupdetails><contactname>sps14</contactname><phonenumber>4739068</phonenumber></usergroupdetails><usergroupdetails><contactname>youtility14</contactname><phonenumber>6756</phonenumber></usergroupdetails>
[2014-07-07 17:16:07,853]  INFO - LogMediator service called = Group_seq1, userid1 = 395885751788635281, userdetails = <usergroupdetails><contactname>sps14</contactname><phonenumber>4739068</phonenumber></usergroupdetails><usergroupdetails><contactname>youtility14</contactname><phonenumber>6756</phonenumber></usergroupdetails>
[2014-07-07 17:16:07,867]  INFO - LogMediator service called = atest, userid1 = 395885751788635281, usergroupid = 400431610974963490, userdetails = <usergroupdetails><contactname>sps14</contactname><phonenumber>4739068</phonenumber></usergroupdetails><usergroupdetails><contactname>youtility14</contactname><phonenumber>6756</phonenumber></usergroupdetails>
[2014-07-07 17:16:07,868]  INFO - LogMediator service called = atest after payload, userid1 = sps14youtility14
[2014-07-07 17:16:07,870]  INFO - LogMediator service called = test, usergroupid = 400431610974963490, userdetail = <userdetails><usergroupdetails><contactname>sps14</contactname><phonenumber>4739068</phonenumber></usergroupdetails><usergroupdetails><contactname>youtility14</contactname><phonenumber>6756</phonenumber></usergroupdetails></userdetails>
[2014-07-07 17:16:07,880]  INFO - LogMediator service called = Group seq2, usergroupid = 400431610974963490, userdetails = <userdetails><usergroupdetails><contactname>sps14</contactname><phonenumber>4739068</phonenumber></usergroupdetails><usergroupdetails><contactname>youtility14</contactname><phonenumber>6756</phonenumber></usergroupdetails></userdetails>
[2014-07-07 17:16:07,880]  INFO - LogMediator service called = Group seq2, usergroupid = 400431610974963490, userdetails = <userdetails><usergroupdetails><contactname>sps14</contactname><phonenumber>4739068</phonenumber></usergroupdetails><usergroupdetails><contactname>youtility14</contactname><phonenumber>6756</phonenumber></usergroupdetails></userdetails>
[2014-07-07 17:16:07,881]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:fef5c93d-a70f-4569-b7fc-a68b8be53c8f, Direction: response, Message = user exist..directly inserting details in musergroupdetail
[2014-07-07 17:16:07,881]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:41855f56-eb26-49d4-8eaf-2bc23878e830, Direction: response, Message = user exist..directly inserting details in musergroupdetail
[2014-07-07 17:16:07,884]  INFO - LogMediator CappGroupService = inside outSequence
[2014-07-07 17:16:07,890]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:96db545a-00f4-4521-8aca-8c8c9a1b6eb5, Direction: response, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><Fault><faultcode>axis2ns116:Client</faultcode><faultstring>The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is http://localhost:9764/services/Capp_GroupDataService/ and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.</faultstring><detail/></Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2014-07-07 17:16:07,890]  INFO - LogMediator Capp_UserGroupDetail_Seq = just before send
[2014-07-07 17:16:07,892]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:f0309d34-1ad1-440b-bba9-2a77893909e2, Direction: response, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><axis2ns117:REQUEST_STATUS xmlns:axis2ns117="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">SUCCESSFUL</axis2ns117:REQUEST_STATUS></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2014-07-07 17:16:07,892]  INFO - LogMediator Capp_UserGroupDetail_Seq = just before send
```

But at the client side it showing previous sequence output as:

```
{"Capp_insert_into_musergroupdetails_op":{"usergroupid":"400423758575175449","userid":"400329480066827979"}}
```

why so?? as per my configuration my custom payloadfactory is correct..because i have used same configuration before and it's working fine their..then why should not here??is their any error?or what else??please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it right now, but you didn't set the media type to the payload factory:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
   .... your xml here ....
</payloadFactory
```

Instead you could also directly provide the correct JSON body with *media-type="json"*.
(see also http://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator)

Comment: thank u kasp3r for reply..i have tried with media-type="xml" but it doesn't work

Comment: Please remove the property RESPONSE=true in Group_seq3. Are you sure "Group_seq3" is called? I can't see the log entry "service called = Group_seq3". And your backend service "Capp_GroupDataService" seems to return a fault, so the FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT property forces the execution of the fault sequence.

Comment: Actually in Group_seq2 i have put a filter..in then part of filter it executes Group_seq3 and in else it it execute Group_seq4..i have put log while executing else part that is why Group_seq2 is not their in log

Comment: and thanks again for reply..i have tried with these property changes but still not working